# How to use OpenTheory to transfer theorems in HOL-light format to theorems in Isabelle format

Tags: isabelle, hol

Currently, I have several theorems in HOL-light formats (along with proof) and I would like to transfer them into theorems in Isabelle formats. I know OpenTheory (http://www.gilith.com/opentheory/) could make it, but I have no idea where to start because I couldn't find any detailed tutorials/examples that I can refer to. Therefore, I am wondering where could be a good point to start. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/xrchz/isabelle-opentheory seems to be it, but it was never updated to Isabelle 2020 apparently.

Comment: cross posted: https://www.reddit.com/r/isabelle/comments/jj562u/how_to_use_opentheory_to_transfer_theorems_in/